# How to stop supervisor process with piped command

Tags: linux, bash, supervisord

I want to send server logs to the telegram bot. Here's my supervisor config:

```
[program:telegram-log-nginx]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=bash -c 'tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log | /usr/share/telegram_log.sh nginx'
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=1
```

When I stop supervisor

```
supervisorctl stop telegram-log-nginx:*
```

the process is still running:

```
ps aux | grep telegram
www-data 32151  0.0  0.0  21608  3804 ?        S    20:53   0:00 /bin/bash /usr/share/telegram_log.sh nginx
```

Is there a proper way to stop all processes?

telegram_log.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
CHATID="chat"
KEY="key"

SERVICE=$1

TIME="10"
URL="https://api.telegram.org/bot$KEY/sendMessage"

while IFS= read -r line; do
  read -r -d '' TEXT <<- EOM
  Service: $SERVICE
  $line
EOM
  curl -s --max-time $TIME -d "chat_id=$CHATID&disable_web_page_preview=1&text=$TEXT" $URL >/dev/null
done

├─supervisord,1101 /usr/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
  │   ├─php,643187 /var/www/web/artisan queue:work
  │   ├─php,643188 /var/www/web/artisan queue:work
  │   ├─php,643189 /var/www/web/artisan queue:work
  ├─systemd,640839 --user
  │   └─(sd-pam),640841
  ├─systemd-journal,406
  ├─systemd-logind,1102
  ├─systemd-resolve,807
  ├─systemd-timesyn,684
  │   └─{systemd-timesyn},689
  ├─systemd-udevd,440
  ├─tail,643203 -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
  ├─telegram_log.sh,643204 /usr/share/telegram_log.sh nginx
```

Comment: Does supervisord let you kill the whole cgroup for the process, as systemd does? If so, that's where I'd start.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've tried stopasgroup=true, it didn't help

Comment: Interesting. I'd really want to let someone who knows supervisor jump in here -- I know bash pretty well, and systemd by necessity, but my preferred init system is the daemontools suite; I don't really know supervisor at all.

Comment: That said... if you have the `nullglob` option enabled, `telegram-log-nginx:*` can be removed from the argument list by the shell before `supervisorctl` ever sees it, making the command just `supervisorctl stop`. Always safer to quote arguments that can potentially be interpreted as globs; `supervisorctl stop 'telegram-log-nginx:*'`.

Comment: BTW, have you considered using strace, sysdig, &c. here to track what's going on? If you can show that bash is being sent a signal but ignoring it, that makes this much more answerable; whereas if you can show that it _isn't_ being sent a signal, then you've proved that it's not a bash problem at all and _only_ a supervisor problem, so the problem can be simplified in that direction.

Comment: BTW, I'd consider something like `bash -c 'exec < <(exec tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log); exec /usr/share/telegram_log.sh nginx'` if you want to have signals go straight to the shell executing `telegram_log.sh`, instead of the one setting up the pipeline. (That means it's _not_ going to the copy of `tail`, but `tail` will exit when it tries to write to stdout and gets a SIGPIPE).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy added bash script to the description

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the process is still running after `bash -c 'exec < <(exec tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log); exec /usr/share/telegram_log.sh nginx'`

Comment: I'd suggest inspecting `pstree -a -p` to look at what parts of the tree are and aren't getting shut down.

Comment: BTW, filling out `TEXT` that way is pretty unnecessarily inefficient. Multi-line string literals are a thing, and heredocs create temporary files to operate. (While I'm kibitzing on things not directly related to your problem -- all-caps variable names are in space reserved for names that are meaningful to the shell; your own variables should use lower-case names. See relevant standard @ https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that because setting a shell variable overwrites like-named environment variables, the convention applies to both).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy added pstree output

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've tried to remove "while" loop from the script and it helped, so maybe it ignores kill signal?

Comment: You've added the `pstree` output when the service is up. How about when it's supposed to be down but isn't?

Comment: And no, `while` doesn't ignore SIGTERM as a general-purpose rule. On the other hand, `while foo; do bar; baz; done` looks only at whether `foo` exited with a successful status; it doesn't take into account failures in `bar` or `baz` in determining whether to continue looping. If you want failures elsewhere to cause the loop to fail, that's what `|| break` is for.

Comment: ...okay, that's helpful. So the copy of bash that started the pipeline dies, but the individual pipeline components still live. That implies that you should be able to write a trap that handles SIGTERM to kill the children (either one, the `tail` _or_ the shell script).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it looks like tail and telegram_log.sh detach from supervisord and remain on a parent level

Comment: Yeah, that's normal. The signal only gets delivered to the immediate child unless you tell your supervisor to do something different. (That said, the code I gave you with the `exec`s _does_ do something different, because it makes that parent shell replace itself with the `telegram_log.sh` instance).

Comment: ...honestly, I'd be very curious to see the `pstree` with the code with the `exec`s, both in the running-as-normal and expected-shutdown cases.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a new enough version of bash that process substitutions update `$!`, you can have your parent script store the PIDs of both its direct children and signal them explicitly during shutdown:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# make our stdin come directly from tail -f; record its PID
exec < <(exec tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log); tail_pid=$!

# start telegram_log.sh in the background inheriting our stdin; record its PID
/usr/share/telegram_log.sh nginx & telegram_script_pid=$!

# close our stdin to ensure that we don't keep the tail alive -- only
# telegram_log.sh should have a handle on it
exec </dev/null

# define a cleanup function that shuts down both subprocesses
cleanup() { kill "$tail_pid" "$telegram_script_pid"; }

# tell the shell to call the cleanup function when receiving a SIGTERM, or exiting
trap cleanup TERM EXIT

# wait until telegram_log.sh exits and exit with the same status
wait "$telegram_script_pid"
```

This means your config file might become something more like:

```
command=bash -c 'exec < <(exec tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log); tail_pid=$!; /usr/share/telegram_log.sh nginx & telegram_script_pid=$!; exec </dev/null; cleanup() { kill "$tail_pid" "$telegram_script_pid"; }; trap cleanup TERM EXIT; wait "$telegram_script_pid"'
```

Comment: Tried your solution on a production server, it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@CharlesDuffy has provided the answer

```
bash -c 'tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log | /usr/share/telegram_log.sh nginx'
```

should be

```
bash -c 'exec < <(exec tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log); exec /usr/share/telegram_log.sh nginx'
```

Comment: Wait, so the earlier suggestion _did_ work? Do you know why it failed when you tried it earlier?